# sql "like" expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I put `like` expression into `SQL` statement like this?

```
select @Count = SUM(cast(Value as int)) 
from tTag
where Name like '[Car],[Truck],[Bike]'
```

Comment: you could connect each statement with an or and write multple likes

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: this is only an example

Comment: @M.Ay:- Your example is fine but what you are trying to achieve is not clear.(*If you are looking for an exact match of names then it can be achieved using IN and if you are looking for pattern then you can use OR*) Also you should tag the database which you are using.

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `tsql` tags based on the non-standard syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for whole words use:

```
where Name = 'Car' or Name = 'Truck' or Name = 'Bike' --or
where Name = '[Car]' or Name = '[Truck]' or Name = '[Bike]' --or
where Name in ('Car', 'Truck', 'Bike') --or
where Name in ('[Car]', '[Truck]', '[Bike]')
```

If you are searching as parts of words then use:

```
where Name like '%Car%' or Name like '%Truck%' or Name like '%Bike%'
```

But if you are searching for strings like `some text [car] some text` then this won't work:

```
where Name like '%[Car]%' or Name like '%[Truck]%' or Name like '%[Bike]%'
```

because `%[Car]%` this will match for example `some text ca some text`. You should escape `[` and `]` symbols. But it depends on database engine. For example for `Sql Server`:

```
 where Name like '%\[Car\]%' ESCAPE '\' or 
       Name like '%\[Truck\]%' ESCAPE '\' or 
       Name like '%\[Bike\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will add *wildcards* in `like` operator else you can use `IN` operator. Try this.

```
Select @Count = SUM(cast(Value as int)) 
from tTag
where Name like '[Car]' 
   or Name like '[Truck]'
   or Name like '[Bike]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking exact matches, try `IN (...)`:

```
 where Name in ('[Car]', '[Truck]', '[Bike]')
```

or

```
 where Name in ('Car', 'Truck', 'Bike')
```

depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @Count = SUM(cast(Value as int)) from tTag
 where Name like '[Car]' or Name like '[Truck]' or name like '[Bike]'
```

Comment: you'd better explain why he has to do that